# How to renew aws reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I purchased a reserved instance in Singapore region on April 17 2017. The instance is going to expire on April 11 2018. Is there any way to renew the my reserved instance before expiration.

Comment: I'm not quite sure it's related to programming :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AWS portal we'll get to know only this..

It’s not currently possible to schedule an EC2 Reserved Instance to auto-renew, or to purchase Reserved Instances in advance. Reserved Instances are active as soon as they’re successfully purchased.

To view your active Reserved Instances and see when they expire, check the Amazon EC2 console.

Note: Reserved Instances apply to a specific region, so make sure to check all regions where you have created Reserved Instances.

Comment: So while expiring my reserved instance should I need purchase a new reserved instance to use the service again?

Comment: It's Yes according to my knowledge..!

Comment: @Eleenajose - your instance will keep running, you'll just be charged at the higher rate until you purchase a new reservation. See [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-reserved-instances.html), particularly the picture.

Comment: Once I purchased a reserved instance and i launched an instance with the same specification of the reserved instance. But in billing the launched instance is shown as on-demand instance.May I know the steps to launch an ec2 instance from a reserved instance?

Comment: @Eleenajose if your instance matches RI params, it will be billed with discount. same region, same instance type, operating system, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although the reservation must be manually renewed, from May 2019 you can be alerted by email prior to reservation expiry using the cost explorer tool.

Here is an excerpt from [this aws announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/reservation-expiration-alerts-now-available-in-aws-cost-explorer/):

To turn on reservation expiration alerts, navigate to the Reservation Summary page, locate the reservation expiration Key Performance Indicator (KPI) in the top right corner, and click on the “Manage alerts” link. From there, simply indicate when you would like to receive reservation expiration alerts, and AWS will begin monitoring your reservation portfolio and automatically send you alerts. Reservation expiration alerts are supported for Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift, Amazon ElastiCache, and Amazon Elasticsearch reservations.